# who can give me some suggestion on DeviceOne?

Tags: javascript, cross-platform

recently, i want to develop android and ios App,but i don't want to use phonegap,i heard that deviceone product can cross platform for javascript and all component UI is native UI, who ever used DeviceOne?
http://www.deviceone.net

Comment: i don't want learn c#,use  javascript may be the best choose!

Answer (score 0):

Look at Sencha Touch: [www.sencha.com](http://www.sencha.com). It's full Javascript framework.